# Live streaming using windows server 2008, Media service and Windows media encoder 9

Tags: c#, .net, windows, encoding, broadcasting

Currently I'm using  windows server 2008, Media service and Windows media encoder 9 to do broadcasting. I'm wrote code to create and delete publishing points in windows media service. right now i am accessing web camera and encoding capture video and push it on window server 2008 using Windows Media Encoder 9. But i want to write my own encoder to acess web camera , encoding capture video and push it on window server 2008 using windows media encoder 9 SDK or Window Media Encoder exe in C#.
So, is there any one have any example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Windows Media Encoder SDK or Expression 4 SDK to create your own app using C#, both works fine, and Microsoft recommends Expression SDK over the other one. Read more here and see the code samples.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff724699(v=expression.40).aspx